# Python interactive shell autocomplete shows more methods in an object then with using __dir__ or __dict__

Tags: python

Playing with Python 3.4, I noticed that in the interactive shell, I can press TAB to get a list of methods for a given object. I thought at first it was a new feature, but then I realized it was just not turned on in previous versions (at least in my installation). So I played it a little bit and I noticed something strange. Using this feature on the `map` object, I get the following properties\methods available:

```
>>> map.<TAB>
map.__base__(           map.__dir__(            map.__hash__(           map.__mro__             map.__reduce_ex__(      map.__text_signature__
map.__bases__           map.__doc__             map.__init__(           map.__name__            map.__repr__(           map.__weakrefoffset__
map.__basicsize__       map.__eq__(             map.__instancecheck__(  map.__ne__(             map.__setattr__(        map.mro(
map.__call__(           map.__flags__           map.__itemsize__        map.__new__(            map.__sizeof__(         
map.__class__(          map.__format__(         map.__iter__(           map.__next__(           map.__str__(            
map.__delattr__(        map.__ge__(             map.__le__(             map.__prepare__(        map.__subclasscheck__(  
map.__dict__            map.__getattribute__(   map.__lt__(             map.__qualname__        map.__subclasses__(     
map.__dictoffset__      map.__gt__(             map.__module__          map.__reduce__(         map.__subclasshook__(
```

While, using `dir` or `__dict__` on the `map` object, give the following properties, which are a lot less then the properties listed above:

```
>>> dir(map)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__next__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

I know that each class is free to implement `__dir__` however it want.. but then I'm just asking myself how the autocomplete feature is able to retrieve more methods then those visible with `__dir__`, and if there are other methods to work around `__dir__` that can be used to get all real methods.

I do know that it's impossible to get a real complete list of all attributes of an object, since a user is free to implement `__getattr__` however she wants, given a string as a key. But, most objects don't have that complex behavior, and I would really just like to mimic the behavior of that TAB auto complete.

***UPDATE***

So, the documentation of `dir` says that if its given a *class* object, it prints out its attributes and its bases' attributes (not including it's own `__class__` attribute, which is a `type` object). So that's why `dir` didn't print out attributes belong to `type`. But even when trying to get the attributes of `type` via `dir(type)`, we get an additional attribute `__abstractmethods__`, which is not a valid attribute when trying to access it (i.e. `type.__abstractmethods__` ==> *AttributeError*), and the auto-complete feature really didn't print that attribute. So all I'm trying to figure out here, is how that auto-complete mechanism  works.

Answer (score 0):

On Python 3.3.5 (linux) I get:

```
>>> dir(map)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__next__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
>>> dir(type(map))
['__abstractmethods__', '__base__', '__bases__', '__basicsize__', '__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dictoffset__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__flags__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__instancecheck__', '__itemsize__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__mro__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__prepare__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasscheck__', '__subclasses__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakrefoffset__', 'mro']
```

so it looks like autocomplete is aggregating both of these data sets.

NOTE: Both of these are accessible from `map`:

```
>>> map.__str__
<slot wrapper '__str__' of 'object' objects>
>>> map.__str__({})
'{}'
>>> map.__bases__
(<class 'object'>,)
```

**UPDATE**: According to http://bugs.python.org/issue10006, "type has no `__abstractmethods__`, so it should raise an `AttributeError`. Note descriptors are allowed to raise `AttributeError` even if they're in `dir()`."

Thus, you can create a function like:

```
def autocomplete(item):
    entries  = set(dir(item))
    entries |= set(dir(type(item)))
    for attr in sorted(entries):
        try:
            a = getattr(item, attr)
            if hasattr(a, '__call__'):
                yield '%s.%s(' % (item.__name__, attr)
            else:
                yield '%s.%s' % (item.__name__, attr)
        except AttributeError:
            # Methods in `dir(x)` are allowed to raise `AttributeError`.
            pass
```

This can be used like:

```
print('\n'.join(autocomplete(map)))
```

On my machine with Python 3.3.5, this gives everything in your autocomplete example except `map.__text_signature__` which I suspect is related to the version of Python I am using.

A `set` is used as there are duplicated attributes in `item` and `type(item)`.

Comment: Well, you almost got it, but one item in those lists in missing in the shell auto complete - the `__abstractmethods__` atrribute (which is really not a valid attribute of `map`). There are total of 44 items in those lists combined together (without duplicates), and in the shell auto-complete there are 43. I found something else.. I can call `object.__dir__(map)` and it gives me a list of 42 attributes - all attributes suggested by the auto-complete but 1 - the `__next__` attribute. It's pretty strange...